# React-konva render dynamic Text inside Shape

Tags: reactjs, react-konva

I am Rendering shape name at bottom center of shape something like this. (Shape name is dynamic)

[image]

First approach---> I tried to render Shape name inside of Group of Shape but the problem i am facing when text name length increase it start affecting shape width. So i move to another way

Second Approach---> I have move Group of Shape name Outside group of Shape with same position of Shape. Here is my calculation for this

```
//on name change this will make move rechtangle to exact x position
if (shapeRef.current?.attrs?.x) {
  nameRef?.current?.parent.x(
    shapeRef.current?.attrs?.x - (nameRef?.current?.textWidth + 4) / 2
  );
}//this will move Child group same as shape group 
if (shapeRef.current?.attrs?.y) {
  nameRef?.current?.parent?.y(
     shapeRef.current?.attrs?.y +
          shapeRef?.current?.attrs?.height / 2 -
          7
  );
}//This will move shape to bottom area
```

**This is working perfectly fine until i introduce rotation**
as soon as Parent rotation change This calculations fails as now i Need to move some time x and sometime y.

Here is example [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-lake-qkkois?file=/src/index.js)

**What i am looking for is Text should stay at bottom center**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you place a text, make sure it follows the same coordinate system flow and rotation logic. Using group you can do this:

```html
      <Group
        rotation={shapeProps.rotation}
        listening={false}
        x={shapeProps.x}
        y={shapeProps.y}
        offset={{
          x: shapeProps.width / 2,
          y: shapeProps.height / 2
        }}
      >
        <Rect
          ref={nameRefShape}
          height={15}
          width={textWidth} //this does not change as state change
          cornerRadius={5}
          fill="#000"
          x={shapeProps.width / 2 -textWidth / 2}
          y={shapeProps.height}
        />
        <Text
          ref={nameRef}
          x={shapeProps.width / 2 - textWidth / 2}
          y={shapeProps.height}
          text={shapeProps.name}
          ellipsis={true}
          //height={20}
          align="center"
          verticalAlign="middle"
          fontSize={13}
          fontFamily="Calibri"
          fill="#fff"
          background="#000"
          zIndex={3}
        />
      </Group>
```

About the next width issue, don't change Konva attribute manually. User react and its state instead:

```js
const [textWidth, setTextWidth] = React.useState(0);

React.useEffect(() => {
    //on name change this will make rechtangle equal to text length width
    setTextWidth(nameRef?.current?.getTextWidth() + 6);
}, [shapeProps]);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-frost-j4shrc?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Hey Iavrton, How are you? Could you please help me out to set the positioning of the length of line? I need to display length value at the center of a line. I have posted a question on SO here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76525337/